# css transform3d and stacking order

Tags: html, css, z-index, translate3d

I use [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to layout some items. Each item includes a popup menu. Because isotope uses `translate3d` in order to layout and animate the items the stacking order of the menus us all messed up. A later item hides the menu of a former one, even though the items have `z-index: 1` and the menus have `z-index: 2`. Is there any way to solve this?

Here is an example that shows the behavior ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paskQ/2/)):

CSS:

```
.items {
    position: relative;
}

.item {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background: lightgray;
    padding: 5px;
}

.menubutton {
    position: relative;
}

.menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    background: yellow;
}

.menubutton .menu {
    display: none;
}

.menubutton:hover .menu {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="items">
<div class="item" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(10px,10px,0px); transform: translate3d(10px,10px,0px);">
<div class="menubutton">
    <div class="label">menu</div>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>                    
    </ul>
</div>
    ...
</div>
<div class="item" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(10px,120px,0px); transform: translate3d(10px,120px,0px);">
<div class="menubutton">
    <div class="label">menu</div>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>                    
    </ul>
</div>
    ...
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just got an idea how to solve it. I just added this style:

```
.item:hover {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

This way the currently hovered item is always in front of all the others.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/paskQ/5/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each `.item` has the same `z-index`, so each subsequent `.item` is being stacked on top of the previous, despite having the same `z-index.` The parent `z-index` is then what is being compared, instead of the `z-index` on `.menu`.

I am not familiar with isotope, so this may not be a viable solution, but if you are able to add some jQuery, you could dynamically set the `z-index` values after and fix the issue with something like

```
var total = $(".item").length;
$(".item").each(function(){
   $(this).css("z-index", total);
   total--;        
});
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/paskQ/4/

Let me know if that doesn't work and maybe I can find an alternate solution, or if you have any questions.

Comment: No that's not very feasible. I also use infiniscroll, which adds more and more items as you scroll down the page. But you gave me an idea, this style solves it: `.item:hover { z-index: 2; }` See: http://jsfiddle.net/paskQ/5/